# How to validate two text box in jquery using notequal function?

Tags: jquery

I want to know, How to set validation for textbox 2 is not equal to textbox 1 in
JQuery?

I am trying,

```
rule:{
textbox1: {
required: true
}
textbox2: {
required: true,
notequalto: '#textbox1'
}
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: The `required:true` part is working?

Comment: yeah. required is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an anonymous function to element (let's say it'd be #textbox2 in your case) which will be  checking value in previous textbox.

You will have something like this:

```
$( "#textbox2" ).change(function() {
  // your validation goes here - take the value from textbox1 and 
  // compare it with value from textbox2
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/change/) you can see a small example of what I'm saying.

Comment: i'm a beginner. i don't know how get the value and compare. can you give an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom method checking both textbox values

```
$.validator.addMethod('notequalto', function (value, element, param) {
    return value != $(param).val(); 
}, 'Both values are same!');


textbox2: {
   required: true,
   notequalto: '#textbox1'
}
```

Comment: can you share html code , is `#textbox1` is textarea or input tag